# Need to know which of two buttons was pressed before for a third button event handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hey guys first month student here , I need to handle a button event based on which button was clicked before , any simple ideas ? ..(example I've got a listbox with a list of actors and depending on if I click "new actor(first button)" or "modify actor(second button)" I need to either add a new actor or modify the existing actor's stats with the "add button (third button --> needs to know which button was clicked before)".. ??

Comment: Store an indicator in a variable???

Comment: As suggested by @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, declare a variable at the FORM LEVEL that you can change when one of those buttons is pressed.  This way you'll know which button was pressed last.  This variable could be of type Button, String, or even possibly an enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable of type `Button` to save the button clicked before.

Note: use Null-conditional operator `?.` to avoid potential exception `System.NullReferenceException`.

```
Button btn;

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(btn?.Name); // print button name
}

private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn = btnNew;
}

private void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn = btnModify;
}
```